# Unique setup for spatial mic array and phase issues?

Tags: microphone, phase

I am working on a project that uses a grid of 16 speakers roughly 8 feet on center.  The speakers are ceiling mounted and down fire into a space.  The playback/spatialization is a custom system that allows sounds to placed anywhere within the grid.

Up until now I have just used mono nature recordings and dispersed them into the grid to create spatialization effects.  I am curious about attempting a more "authentic" spatial audio gathering technique in the field.  Traditional soundfield and ambisonic microphone setups are not of great use, because of the way the audio will be dispersed overhead on a flat grid for playback.

Instead, I am curious about placing 8 microphones in a grid pattern in an outdoor area.  And then playing back these recordings by placing them in 8 zones across the 16 channel speaker array.  My main question involves phase issues.  Is a setup like this simply not possible due to phase interference?  Or is there a way that I could position microphones that would minimize phase problems?

Any thoughts or input are welcome.

Comment: Can you please clarify the speaker setup grid? I am ok with "Grid", but "roughly 8 feet on centre" isn't entirely clear to me. Is it simply a square 4x4 grid with 2ft between each speaker?

Comment: Hi mark!  There are 16 speakers setup in a 4x4 grid formation with 8' between each speaker.  So it i would be roughly 24' x 24' if you measured the total coverage of the speakers.

Comment: The best way to position microphones to minimise phase issues is to use a coincident technique. Use either X/Y or M/S mics. M/S is probably more practical and useful for field recording in this scenario.